# Subscription failed using Stripe API in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make an add-on using `Google Apps Script` & `Stripe` where user can subscribe for an item as an yearly subscription. Every time I purchase the subscription from Stripe checkout, I get error like this,

```
{
  "error": {
   "code": "parameter_unknown",
   "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
   "message": "Received unknown parameter: @45b5a607",
   "param": "@45b5a607",
   "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

When I check the log in Stripe Dashboard I get the POST body like this,

```
{
  "items": "[Ljava.lang.Object",
  "@45b5a607": null,
  "customer": "cus_Dix0eSYM5qP0kx"
}
```

This is my code in Google Apps Script,

```
var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
};

var customer = {
  'email': customerEmail,
  'source': token
};

var optCreate = {
  'method' : 'post',
  "headers" : headers,
  'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'payload' : customer,
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};

var createCustomer = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlCreate, optCreate);
var respCreate = JSON.parse(createCustomer.getContentText());
var customerId = respCreate.id;
if (customerId == null) { return "Error"; }

var data = {
  "customer" : customerId,
  "items" : [
    {
      "plan" : "plan_Diuw7CdAGcSrhm"
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  "headers" : headers,
  'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'payload' : data,
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var resp = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(resp);
```

I think I must be doing something wrong in my `data` JSON object. The `items` field is not working correctly that's why POST body is weird. What is the correct way here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the payload.

```
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  "headers" : headers,
  'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck! :'(

Comment: Now in POST body I get this,
`{
  "{"customer":"cus_DiyHlTwF1aR2YN","items":": {
    "{"plan":"plan_Diuw7CdAGcSrhm"}": {
      "}": null
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're POSTing JSON data, but Stripe's API does not accept JSON — you need to use form encoding. i.e your code needs to set `data` to be in this format:

```
items[0][plan]=plan_CvVNfwZ4pYubYg&customer=cus_Diygqj4wAq6L9T
```

You can refer to [cURL examples](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl#create_subscription) in Stripe's API docs for this. Generally you should use an [official library](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries) to simplify making API requests, but that may not be possible with Apps Script.

Comment: I've already made a script for charging the card in Google Apps Script using JSON. That worked well, but facing issues in the subscription part.